# MS Outlook add-in saveAsync method returns the wrong ID

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm trying to write an Outlook add-in with office-js, which involves saving an email and then later sending it with the MS Graph API.

To do this, I have the `saveAsync` method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/office.context.mailbox.item?view=office-js#saveasyncoptions-callback), which should save the currently open email as a draft, and return its ID. I should then be able to send this message with a call to the Graph API of `POST /me/messages/{id}/send`

However, I'm seeing a slightly different ID get returned by `saveAsync` than the one that actually exists in my drafts folder.

For example, my most recent attempt with save Async gave me:

```
AAMkAGE4ZWVlNjI1LTk3NjAtNDFmYy1hZDhkLTU3ZWY0ZjJiMDk5YgBGAAAAAACghEgqiSFAQo8v+Kh2
wPqEBwDoiTH7R3zxTZ+n2OMFzElyAAAAAAEPAADoiTH7R3zxTZ+n2OMFzElyAAAT/OksAAA=
```

But on inspection in the Graph explorer, the ID was actually:

```
AAMkAGE4ZWVlNjI1LTk3NjAtNDFmYy1hZDhkLTU3ZWY0ZjJiMDk5YgBGAAAAAACghEgqiSFAQo8v_Kh2
wPqEBwDoiTH7R3zxTZ_n2OMFzElyAAAAAAEPAADoiTH7R3zxTZ_n2OMFzElyAAAT-OksAAA=
```

Does anybody know how I can fix the saveAsync method, so that it gives the correct message ID?

Answer (score 2):

*Item IDs retrieved via EWS or via the itemId property use a different format than the format used by REST APIs (such as the [Outlook Mail API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations) or the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph)). The convertToRestId method converts an EWS-formatted ID into the proper format for REST.*

You have to [Converts an item ID formatted for EWS into REST format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox?view=office-js#converttorestiditemid-restversion--string)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it turned out that clearing the cache on my drafts folder ended up working! (although I'm not sure why)

It is possible to use the ID returned by saveAsync to query the REST API. The Office.mailbox.item.id method is the one that needs converting - the saveAsync method is designed to allow you to send the email with REST.

Thanks for the help guys! :)